# How can I parse json array string to array on php

Tags: php, json, parsing

How can I parse json array string to array on php

```
'[{"a": "1", "b": "2"}, {"a": "3"}]'
```

seems [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) allows parse only objects but not arrays. Should it be manually parsed to array before using json_decode?

---

Seems problem in string. I get a variable with json, and if I output it, looks like the json is valid

```
echo($jsonvar); //result [{"title":"Home","id":"/","url":"/"}]
```

but when I try parse string from the variable, the result is nothing even when string is trimmed

```
echo('[{"title":"Home","id":"/","url":"/"}]', true); //nice parsed array
echo($jsonvar, true); //nothing
echo(trim($jsonvar, " \t\n\r\0\x0B"), true); //nothing
```

Comment: How has this gotten two votes? If the documentation was actually read then this question would of never gotten asked. From the doc: `When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.`
`

Comment: Believe or not, `json_decode()` can actually decode JSON; any kind of valid JSON. I can't figure out how you reached a different conclusion.

Comment: The problem has been solved with the following code `json_decode(html_entity_decode($jsonvar));`, Sorry for the dumb question, it cannot be removed because of answers. I thought the reason was in array.

Answer (score 7):

Pass the `true` as a second parameter to your [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse the json string to array.

```
$json='[{"a": "1", "b": "2"}, {"a": "3"}]';
$arr= json_decode($json,true); 
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the json into array by using the true flag in [**`json_decode()`**](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

```
<?php
$str = '[{"a": "1", "b": "2"}, {"a": "3"}]';
$arr=json_decode($str,true);
print_r($arr);
```